# Laravel: The PUT method is not supported for route grades. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST. (Crud functionality)

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, crud

I am working on CRUD functionality in Laravel.

For one reason, my ''save'' button, during working on edit/update does not work.

Keep in mind destroy/delete is not finished yet, therefore the controllers are empty now.

**Create Blade**

```
@extends('common.master')

@section('content')
    <section class="section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="columns">
                <div class="column is-12"> {{-- These divs are needed for proper layout --}}
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('grades.store'),  }}">
                        @method('PUT')
                        @csrf
                        <div class="card"> {{-- The form is placed inside a Bulma Card component --}}
                            <header class="card-header">
                                <p class="card-header-title"> {{-- The Card header content --}}
                                    Add a new Grade
                                </p>
                            </header>

                            <div class="card-content">
                                <div class="content">

                                    {{-- Here are all the form fields --}}
                                    <div class="field">
                                        <label class="label">ID</label>
                                        <div class="control">
                                            <input name="ID" class="input @error('ID') is-danger @enderror"
                                                   type="text" placeholder="Your title here...">
                                        </div>
                                        @error('ID')
                                        <p class="help is-danger">{{ $message }}</p>
                                        @enderror
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="field">
                                        <label class="label">Has Cheated</label>
                                        <div class="control">
                                            <textarea name="excerpt"
                                                      class="textarea @error('Has Cheated') is-danger @enderror"
                                                      type="text" placeholder="A short summary..."></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                        @error('Has Cheated')
                                        <p class="help is-danger">{{ $message }}</p>
                                        @enderror
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="field">
                                        <label class="label">Feedback</label>
                                        <div class="control">
                                            <textarea name="body" class="textarea @error('feedback') is-danger @enderror"
                                                      rows="15" placeholder="The main text of your article..."></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                        @error('feedback')
                                        <p class="help is-danger">{{ $message }}</p>
                                        @enderror
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                <div class="field is-grouped">
                                    {{-- Here are the form buttons: save, reset and cancel --}}
                                    <div class="control">
                                        <button type="submit" class="button is-primary">Save</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="control">
                                        <button type="reset" class="button is-warning">Reset</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="control">
                                        <a type="button" href="/grades" class="button is-light">Cancel</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
@endsection
```

```
*Grade Controller*

class GradeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $grades = Grade::all();
        return view('grades.index', compact('grades'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('grades.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        Grade::create($this->validateGrade($request));
        return redirect(route('grades.index'));

    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Grade  $grade
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Grade $grade)
    {
        return view('grades.show', compact('grade'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Grade  $grade
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Grade $grade)
    {

    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\Grade  $grade
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Grade $grade)
    {
        $grade->update($this->validateGrade($request));

        return redirect(route('grades.index'));
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Grade  $grade
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Grade $grade)
    {
        //
    }

    public function validateGrade(Request $request): array
    {
        return $request->validate([
            'mark' => 'required',
            'has_cheated' => 'required',
            'feedback' => 'required'
        ]);
    }

}
```

Adding the:

Method('PUT') after the @csrf tag didn't change much. Also, when filling in action="/grades/{{ $grade->id }}">, the $grade variable seems undefined?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO ... can you provide the route definitions?

Comment: Please can you provide the routes? If its not definied its most likely missing from there

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Route::resource` to define routes. So the form method of `route('grades.store')` is post and the job of that route is to create a new grade.

In your create.blade, change put method to:

```
@method('POST')
```

To update, you use `route('grades.update', $grade)`. Conference more at https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller